# Selecionar elementos em hierarquia com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma hierarquia da seguinte maneira

```
<li class="clear2 clearfix" id="field_id16">
<span class="row_title">Link: </span>
<span class="row_data">
    <div class="field_uneditable">http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-O7KAb62ChqU/Tb_wIM-9zOI/AAAAAAAAACA/nG7EnK7xAmY/s1600/ydc9ntyrhmi63s0umu4a881dc4018f7_homer-reggae.jpg</div>
</span>
```

Para pegar o link que tem dentro do `span` `row_data` com jQuery consigo usar isso:

```
$('#field_id16 .row_data div').text();
```

Gostaria de saber, como faço para fazer esse seletor onde posso filtrar os elementos com Javascript puro? `#field_id16 .row_data div`

Isso existe no CSS também, mas não sei como usar no Javascript.

Comment: +1 pela imagem do Hommer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se não precisar de usar browsers antigos, ou seja usando IE8 ou mais recente, pode usar o [**.querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector):

```
var elemento = document.querySelector('#field_id16 .row_data div');
console.log(elemento.innerHTML); // http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-O7KAb62ChqU/Tb_wIM-9zOI/AAAAAAAAACA/nG7EnK7xAmY/s1600/ydc9ntyrhmi63s0umu4a881dc4018f7_homer-reggae.jpg
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/es94w/

Comment: @Dang, bem visto, obrigado! Mudei o link para a versão portuguêsa.